# Executing git post-receive hook on windows server

Tags: git

I'm trying to execute a post-receive hook on a windows server git(msysgit) installation - to sync the repo to codebasehq.

The script does nothing more than just wget "url" but it doesn't seem to be executing.
I've renamed the "post-receive.sample" to "post-receive" and installed wget to windows path which works fine via the command prompt.

Is there something I'm not doing here? I would appreciate any insights on how to get this working. Thanks.

Comment: Can you run that script from msysgit command line? Does wget started from that command line work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

Turns out the Shebang on the hook script pointed to /bin in the Git installation directory.

It couldn't find *wget* since wget is not part of the installation. All I had to do was copy *wget* into git's /bin folder and it worked.

On a side note for windows users, *wget* can be downloaded as part of [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/)